# How to add two conditions using let in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use `let` to check two conditions
Lets say if I had to use `if` then this is the condition

```
if (it.data != null && !it.data!!.name.isEmpty()) {}
```

How can I convert it to use `let`
I know that to check null this is what we do

```
it.data?.let {}
```

but I don't know how to check the second part which is if a string is empty or not. Please keep in mind that I have to check that `data` is not null AND `data.name` is not empty

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: How about, `it.data?.let {mData->  if (mData.name.isEmpty()) {}  }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your specific case you could use `takeIf`

```
it.data
   ?.takeIf { data ->  data.name.isNotEmpty() }
   ?.let { data -> ...}
```

Comment: wow, very nice idea, you could perhaps simplify this further by making use of `.isNotEmpty()` instead of negating the isEmpty

Comment: True, I adapted it

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer without `let`

```
if (it.data?.name?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
   // data is not null and name is not empty
}
```

Comment: @RobinVinzenz No, it is needed since the value can be `null` :)

Comment: You are right @hakim =) Deleted comment again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below snippet helps you :

```
it.data?.name?.isNotEmpty(){}
```